# SocketIO Not Emitting an Action in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

**The Goal**
I am looking for numerous users to sign into a game room, such as `game/#####`. When a user hits that url, their user object is created and shared to the state for any other user in that room to view.

**The Problem**
In `componentDidMount` I call my Socket api function and pass in the `userObj` and `room` value. This information makes it to the api function, and then to the server listener as well. However, when the server emits the `join room` event, the frontend doesn't seem to hear it and respond by updating the `state.game.users` object with the new user.

**The Code**

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('join room', (userObj, room) => {
    socket.join(room).emit('join room', userObj);
  });

  socket.on('join chat', (msgObj, room) => {
    socket.in(room).emit('join chat', msgObj);
  });

  socket.on('chat message', (msgObj, room) => {
    socket.in(room).emit('chat message', msgObj);
  });
});
```

**api.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

export const joinRoom = (userObj, room) => {
  socket.emit('join room', userObj, room);
}

export const joinChat = (msgObj, room) => {
  socket.emit('join chat', msgObj, room);
}

export const chatMessage = (msgObj, room) => {
  socket.emit('chat message', msgObj, room);
}
```

**component**

```
import { joinRoom, joinChat, chatMessage } from './../../api';

class GameBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      game: {
        id: props.match.params.gameid,
        users: {},
        messages: []
      }
    };

    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');

    this.postUsername = this.postUsername.bind(this);
    this.getBoardValues = this.getBoardValues.bind(this);
    this.buildUserData = this.buildUserData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on('join room', (userObj) => {
      this.postUser(userObj);
    });

    this.socket.on('join chat', (msgObj) => {
      this.postMessage(msgObj);
    });

    this.socket.on('chat message', (msgObj) => {
      this.postMessage(msgObj);
    });

    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      joinRoom(this.buildUserData(), this.state.game.id);
    });
  }

  postUser(userObj) {
    const game = this.state.game;
    game.users[userObj.id] = userObj;
    this.setState({ game });
  }
...
```

**Repo**
https://github.com/yuschick/horror-bingo

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');`. It means you create another connection to your server with a new socket. So when you emit a new event from server, your socket in the component cannot receive it because it has a different socket.

You can `export const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');`, import it into your component and use it `socket.on ...`

In case you want to emit an event to another connected socket, you can use `socket.broadcast.emit` or `io.emit`. You can check the cheat sheet here https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/. For example:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join room', (userObj, room) => {
        socket.join(room).emit('join room', userObj); \\<-- this will only let the socket from front end which emit 'join room' receive event

        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit(`join room', userObj); \\<-- this will let all socket from front end(in the same room) receive 'join room' event except the one which emit.
    });

    socket.on('join chat', (msgObj, room) => {
        socket.in(room).emit('join chat', msgObj);
    });

    socket.on('chat message', (msgObj, room) => {
        socket.in(room).emit('chat message', msgObj);
    });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense but doesn't appear to fix the issue. Still only one user in each browser's state.

Comment: @Yuschick maybe I still haven't cleared about your issue. I have tried and the front end can receive server event. You can try console log something when front end receive those event ? And as I mention, in server if you still use `socket.emit`, only that socket can receive event. So if a player join and you want other player know, you will have to use `socket.broadcast.emit`